# Comment icon for text widget is not showing

Tags: ios, swift, pdf-annotations

I am trying to add a comment icon in pdfView for widget type text. I have used the property iconType. But the icon is not showing. Your help is much appreciated.

`let annotationBounds = CGRect(x: 169, y: 400, width: 40, height: 40)
        let commentAnnotation = PDFAnnotation(bounds: annotationBounds, forType: .text, withProperties: nil)
        commentAnnotation.iconType = .note
        pdfView.currentPage?.addAnnotation(commentAnnotation)`